# How to extract fixed number of characters from string in JMeter using regular expression extractor?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have the following part of a JSON response:

"created_at":"2017-05-08T14:01:25.903Z"

How should I configure my "Regular Expression Extractor" in JMeter to extract the first 10 characters from this JSON response: ***2017-05-08***.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following pattern:

```
"created_at":"([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*?"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :-) !

Answer (score 1):

If the syntax is always the same, you can use this one :
`\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/wRii3m/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you need first 10 characters only the relevant regular expression would be as simple as

```
"created_at":"(.{1,10})
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regex First N Characters]

References:

- [Apache JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Comment: Thanks for your help :-) !